# editor for main.m that retains formatting, i.e. colors

Tags: xcode, editor

Configuration: Mac Mini with OS X 10.9.5, XCode v 6.1.1.

I'd like to be able to share my main.m and other text files generated by XCode and still maintain the formatting and colors.  Is there a recommendation for doing this or for a particular text editor?  I tried copying and pasting into Libre Office but all the colors are lost, though the tabs and spacing were preserved.

Thanks for any help,

Kevin H.

Comment: XCode colors text according to syntax rules.  It doesn't save the colors with the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste text copied from Xcode into Pages, it will retain the colors, font selection, and formatting. It won't retain the background color, though.

I'm pretty TextEdit will retain the formatting (minus the background color) if you paste into a rich text document, too.

You can also try printing the source code to a PDF from Xcode, although I'm not sure how much of the formatting Xcode retains when printing.